# @Output not firing method from parent component

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I've been struggling with this problem for some hours and its getting pretty frustrating. 
I have a child component in which in which I need to detect when the mouse hovers over something. The mouseenter event fires correctly and my method within the child component (app-circle) is fired but after I emit() the method from parent component does not get called.

Angular version: 8.0.1

Here is some relevant code:

**Child component (app-circle):**

TS:

```
@Output() mouseEnter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
...
public onMouseEnter() {
   this.mouseEnter.emit();
}
```

HTML:

```
<a (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter()"> ... </a>
```

**Parent component:**

HTML:

```
 <app-circle (mouseEnter)="onBackgroundCircleMouseEnter()"> </app-circle>
```

TS:

```
public onBackgroundCircleMouseEnter() {
   console.log('emitted');
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, with the exact code you posted: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmzhvk. Post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz, as I just did, but which does reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `@Output` name, try to change name for something else, it may be overlapping with something internal within angular

Comment: @JBNizet I think this all relevant code. However, when copy-pasted component from stackblitz everything worked as expected. It seems that the problem is it's much more deeper thus, i have no idea what to copy and what to not in order to be able to reproduce it. If you will you can have a look at the entire project (its just few components) https://github.com/AlecFirtulescu/circular-progress-bar

Comment: Since all we know about your code is what you posted, and since what you posted works fine, we can't possibly help until you post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Try to eliminate every stuff you think is unrelated from your code (one by one), and see if the bug is still there, until you come to a minimal example. Doing that has a good chance of allowing you to find the thing that causes the issue by eliminating it and see the problem disappear.

Comment: I've just done that on your code, and the answer is simple: you have two divs on top of each other, and the mouseenter event listener is registered on the background one, which is "hidden" by the foreground one. So it never receives the event. If you remove the foregound (second) one, then it works as expected.

Comment: Oh, shame on me for not realising that. Thank you very much. Can you post an answer to this question so I can set it as correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discovered in the comments, your code is fine. But you have two divs on top of each other, and the mouseenter event listener is registered on the background one, which is "hidden" by the foreground one. So it never receives the event. If you remove the foregound (second) one, then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as expected, If you are using Child Component emit event to Parent.
I have implemented the same logic using directive which will listen for 'mouseenter' event using @Hostlistener and emit an output event.

Here is the stackblitz Code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yniybk?file=src%2Fapp%2FattachMouse.Directive.ts

Answer (score -1):

Try to return any data in emitter, cuz you dedicated the type

`any => EventEmitter<any>`

So I think to try returning anything

```
public onMouseEnter() {
    this.mouseEnter.emit({});
}
```

It may work !!!

I hope that i could help you more